# Linq Queries with not operator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am new to linq and I want to know how to write not equal (!=) in linq queries like in SQL shown here:

```
select 
    projects.Name 
from 
    Projects 
inner join 
    projectPermissions on (projects.FK_Owner_ID != projectpermissions.FK_User_ID and Projects.Project_ID = projectPermissions.FK_Project_ID) 
where 
    ProjectPermissions.FK_User_ID = 53;

var projects = (from project in this.context.Projects
                join shareProjects in this.context.ProjectPermissions on
                       new { UserID = project.FK_Owner_ID, ProjectID = project.Project_ID } equals
                       new { UserID = shareProjects.FK_User_ID, ProjectID = shareProjects.FK_Project_ID }
                where shareProjects.FK_User_ID == userId
                select new
                       {};
```

Comment: Where do you need to write it?

Comment: like in sql i wrote project.FK_Owner_ID!=shareProject.FK_User_ID

Comment: i want not operator between (UserID ) and equals operator between (projectID)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `where` instead, joining supports equal key comparison only:

```
var projects =from project in this.context.Projects
              join shareProjects in this.context.ProjectPermissions on
                   project.Project_ID equals shareProjects.FK_Project_ID
              where  project.FK_Owner_ID != shareProjects.FK_User_ID &&
                     shareProjects.FK_User_ID == userId
              select new{};
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to negate it:

```
on (!(projects.FK_Owner_ID == projectpermissions.FK_User_ID) and Projects.Project_ID = projectPermissions.FK_Project_ID)
```

Comment: its not allow me to do so saying that you cant use the project local variable before its declaration even i declare its first var projcets

Comment: Then cast them first and negate afterwards if it doesn't work for you while casting. I don't know what causes your error. ##EDIT: Try to turn the var projects... before the select.

Comment: operator ! can not be applied to operand of type long

 (!(project.FK_Owner_ID equals shareProjects.FK_User_ID) and project.Project_ID equals shareProjects.FK_Project_ID)

Comment: "and" and  second "equal" also doesn't work ... can u convert the whole sql query into linq please

Comment: I hadn't converted anything, I only wanted to show you how you've to use the operator. And I'm not able to convert it for you, sorry.